# Why my customized neural network not work, and with high MAE

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, regression

This is a regression problem using the DNN, which estimate the income.
The network looks like the following picture:
[image]

[The network struct picture](https://ibb.co/jH02nXY)

The right branch is a fully connected neural network, and its result means the efficient.
The left branch is a known variable for each sample, which means the online hours.
Currently, I only want to learn the right branch of the network. The network code looks like this:

```
def neural_net(x, hours):
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights_h1), biases_h1))
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights_h2), biases_h2))
    efficient_out_layer = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights_out), biases_out))
    delta_efficient = tf.add(efficient_out_layer, 1)
    delta_online_hours = tf.add(hours, 1)
    out_layer = tf.multiply(delta_online_hours, delta_efficient)
    return out_layer
```

But the mae is very high.
When I don't use the left branch, and only use the dnn to estimate the result, the mae is low.

I want to know what is the problem with my network, and why the left branch muliply the trained network of the right branch would enlarge the mae, thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to multiply `x` to the output of right network if you can not figure out what `x` means exactly. The variable `x` may be a feature of your sample. If so, you better input it into the right network with other features, not multiply it to the output simply.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 'x' of the left branch is indeed a feature, which means the working hours of a worker. The right branch means the working efficient and I added a loss of average working efficient of the worker to reduce the loss of the right branch.